# PHP strtotime calculation is shifted by 1 hour

Tags: php, time

What i am doing is:

```
echo date('H:i:s', abs(strtotime("10:50:00 - 08:50:00")));
```

And what i am getting is:

```
03:00:00
```

Timezone settings aint helping.
Different servers / machines act the same. 10-8 must equal to 2 not 3.
I know that easy solution would be -3600. But i want it to work without patching mistakes.

Comment: You are using strtotime incorrectly, you need to convert each of the sums, then minus those `strtotime("10:50:00") - strtotime("08:50:00")`

Comment: What are you doing with strtotime, do you even know what happens when using strtotime?

Comment: Hi Varedis =) Solution that you suggested gives the exact same result as mine above :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
$d1 = new DateTime("10:50:00");
$d2 = new DateTime("08:50:00");
$diff = $d1->diff($d2);
echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: This is the SOLUTION!
But i must mention Boldewyn 1 more time for pointing out the cause of the problem in the first place!

Comment: @JoonasKolostov - that's why Boldewyn got my upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `strtotime` does not calculate *differences*. It tries to parse absolute dates. So the result is `false`. `abs(false) === 0`. Then you're left with

```
date('H:i:s', 0);
```

If your timezone is set to GMT-0300, then `date()` tries to represent 1970-01-01T03:00:00.

Comment: Thanks Boldewyn, that explains the logic behind my code (Y)!

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` converts time to a Unix timestamp, which is basically the time in seconds since 1970, which is an integer.

So you can convert the two times and do a simple subtraction, then convert back using the date.

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime("10:50:00") - strtotime("08:50:00"));
```

Comment: Hi Antony =) Your solution gives the same result as mine :(

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your timezone setting as well. What is the output of `date_default_timezone_get`